# React Native Reducer data not being sent to my page

Tags: react-native, reducers

I have an action data that is being sending to the reducer, but not ti my page constructor.

Action Method:

```
export const getTenantByID = ({ tenantID }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const getTenant = {
      FirstName: 'Jonh', LastName: 'Doe', Email: 'jonh@test.com', Phone: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
      Unit: '101', MiddleName: '',
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_TENANT_DATA,
      payload: getTenant
    });
  };
};
```

Then, in my reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  error: false,
  data: [],
  tenantData: {},
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TENANTS_DATA:
      return { ...state, error: false, data: action.payload };
    case GET_TENANT_DATA:
        return { ...state, error: false, tenantData: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If I do a console.log(action) after the case GET_TENANT_DATA, I can see that data for the payload, so it is working in the reducer.

My page:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
    this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID);
      console.log(this.props); // this show tenantData as a empty object
    this.state = {
      tenantData: this.props.tenantData
    };
  } 
  ...

const mapStateToProps = ({ tenants }) => {
  const { error, tenantData } = tenants;

  return { error, tenantData };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getTenantByID
})(TenantDetails);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using `thunk` and it's asynchronous, so you need to `await` your action so that you can get the updated state after you fire the action. Otherwise, you can remove thunk if it's not necessary. You may want to fire the action in `componentDidMount` instead of constructor too

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.getTenant();
}

getTenant = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
    await this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID); // Wait for action to complete
    console.log(this.props); // Get updated props here
    this.state = {
      tenantData: this.props.tenantData
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ tenants }) => {
  const { error, tenantData } = tenants;

  return { error, tenantData };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getTenantByID
})(TenantDetails);
```

Or you can capture the update via `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.getTenant();
}

componentDidUpdate(previousProps) {
    if (this.props.tenantData !== previousProps.tenantData) {
       console.log(this.props); // Get updated props here
       this.state = {
          tenantData: this.props.tenantData
       };
    }
}

getTenant = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
    this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID);
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ tenants }) => {
  const { error, tenantData } = tenants;

  return { error, tenantData };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getTenantByID
})(TenantDetails);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I'm learning react native. Shouldn't I use redux?

Comment: From my experience, if you are new to react, you can just try to use local state until you facing some problems when you have a more complex state to share or use across components, then you may want to use redux to handle them. Otherwise, local state is sufficient for you. You can read more here https://redux.js.org/faq/general

Comment: For some reason it just stopped working. After the async method the props is not updated.

Comment: You may need to let us know what is the changes you have made, otherwise we can't help